# unable to select packages liblzma-dev (no such package), libxml-dev (no such package) in golang:1.14.9-alpine docker

Tags: docker, go

I have try to build docker image using golang:1.14.9-alpine, and i always getting below error for installing thus libraries , what i need to do install thus libraies ?

ERROR: unable to select packages:
liblzma-dev (no such package):
required by: world[liblzma-dev]
libxml-dev (no such package):
required by: world[libxml-dev]

below my docker file

```
FROM golang:1.14.9-alpine
RUN apk update && apk upgrade \
    && apk --no-cache --update add build-base
RUN apk add --no-cache \
        alpine-sdk \
        protobuf \
        ca-certificates \
        curl \
        make \
        libx11-dev \
        libxslt-dev \
        libxml2 \
        gcc \
        g++ \
        ca-certificates \
        libxml-dev \
        liblzma-dev \
        libxslt-dev
RUN go get github.com/golang/protobuf/proto@v1.4.3
RUN go get github.com/golang/protobuf/protoc-gen-go@v1.4.3
RUN go get  github.com/micro/protoc-gen-micro/v2
RUN export GO111MODULE=on
COPY . .
RUN make build
RUN chmod 765 test-service
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the package is [xz-dev](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/contents?branch=edge&name=xz-dev&arch=x86_64&repo=main)

You can try a multistage build and then copy the required executables to alpine version. It will optimize the build further.

You can try something like this:

```
# Build Stage
FROM golang:1.14.9 as build
...
# Build here
RUN make build 
...

# Release stage
FROM alpine:3.13.5 as release
# Copy only the needed files
COPY --from=build <build output> <exec location>
CMD <exec>
```